# WP Array of posts by part of meta_value

Tags: mysql, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to array posts containing the value X within their meta_value. I’ve go this so far:

```
<?php $pagestack = get_pages( array(
                        ...
                        'meta_value' => 'X'
                    ) );
                        echo '<ul>';
                        foreach ($pagestack as $post){
                            echo '<li>...</li>';
                        }
                        //endforeach;
                        echo '</ul>';
                     ?>
```

This shows me all pages that have an exact meta_value of X. But in fact my meta_values hold more information than just the X. So now I want to check the meta_value first if it CONTAINS this certain value. How can I do that. I can’t figure it out myself.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is confusing because you mention posts yet your query is `"get_pages"` which is for pages, they are not the same.

Regardless of either, you can just do a traditional wordpress loop, and then use `get_post_custom` to return an array of values for 1 field. Also look at the related function in the link.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Is is also worth noting that using `WP Query` gives you a lot more room to work with when using the loop and custom fields as can be seen here, 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: That was in fact my problem. The WP_Query is pretty powerful and gave me all the options I needed. Though I think I wrote way too much code. But I am still learning. Thank you so much for your help.